# Understanding a proof of the Uniform LLN

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I'm trying to understand [this](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~xshi/econ715/Lecture_2_some_asymptotic_theorems.pdf) proof of the uniform law of large numbers. The proof I mean is on page 2, the theorem titled "ULLN1".

First of all, I don't understand the first inequality:

$$\max_k \sup_\theta\left[ \frac1n\sum g(X_i, \theta)-Eg(X_i,\theta) \right]
\leq
\max_k\left[\frac1n\sum\sup_\theta g(X_i, \theta)-E\inf_\theta g(X_i,\theta)\right]$$

Is the idea to forget about the $\max$, and bound each $\sup$ separately? It seems like we're just saying $\sup (a-b)\leq \sup a - \inf b$, is that basically it?

Secondly, two lines down, I get that we're applying the standard LLN, but how do we pull the $o_P(1)$ out of the $\max$?

Finally, I'm not sure I really understand the overall structure of the proof. We basically want to prove $f_n\to f$ uniformly, but instead of trying to bound $\sup|f_n-f|$, it seems like we're separately bounding $\sup(f_n-f)$ and $\inf(f_n-f)$, is that right? Can the proof not be rewritten in a more standard way where we just bound an absolute value directly?

Comment: What does "this proof" refer to in the first line?  Page 2 of what? Did you forget to stick in a URL?  My understanding of the "ULLN" is that it is the LLN for vectors in the Banach space $C(\Theta)$: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469152.

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, I forgot the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your last paragraph: yes, I think the proof sketch given in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469152) does describe the overall structure of the proof you are reading.

The rest of this answer is predicated on knowledge of that answer. I will keep it short (unusually short for me), just giving a hint.

A key step is covering the space of functions with a collection of finitely many compact sets of functions that catch most of the probability mass.   Recall the [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem), which describes relatively compact subsets of continuous functions: they have to bounded, and they have to be equicontinuous.  That is, they cannot wiggle too much, oscillate too much.  The mysterious sup - inf terms in the $\max_k$ expression you ask about has to do with bounding the oscillation of the summand functions over certain $\delta$-balls covering $\Theta$. The $\max$ picks the worst such $\delta$-ball, and guess what, it's tame enough, after all.